# No suitable driver found MariaDB

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, servlet, mariadb

Estou tentando inserir uma tupla de dados em um DB utilizando JDBC através de uma página web.

Fiz uma classe `ConnectionFactory` para encapsular a conexão com o MariaDB, importei o driver para o classpath, **testei inserindo alguns dados com uma classe `Teste` com um `Main` e deu certo**, reconheceu o driver normalmente. Porém, quando utilizo na servlet ele apresenta o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já coloquei o jar do driver dentro da pasta lib do tomcat, já coloquei dentro da `WEB-INF/lib` no deploy do projeto mas nada. Também já coloquei:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

na factory mas sem sucesso.

Comment: o mariadb usa o mesmo driver que o MySQL? Além disso, a porta está certa? Essa porta é a padrão do MySQL.

Comment: Verifique a porta que o mariadb esta rodando e o nome da table que está tentando inserir os dados, já que o erro diz que não existe tal informação.

Comment: Então, fiz um .jar pra rodar por linha de comando utilizando a conexão e deu certo, inseri vários dados... é só quando eu faço o deploy no Tomcat que dá ruim, mesmo utilizando o mesmo driver. De alguma maneira o Tomcat não está reconhecendo o driver, mesmo estando na lib do projeto e do próprio Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é mais necessário especificar o *Class.forName* desde o [**Java SE 6**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/).
Todavia, caso deseje declarar, na [especificação do MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/) diz a classe correta: **org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver**.

Comment: Valeu @brunoandrade.io, de veras tinha colocado com.mysql.jdbc.Driver qd testei i Class.forName por desencargo de consciência. Pra fazer o deploy no Tomcat tem que especificar o forName qd for criar a conexão...